# Can't access object property in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying out angular, I have a home component that displays a list of countries, I want to display more information about the country in a detail view.

I can actually see the data when I pipe it to json in the template but can't access properties of the object.

in the home.html I have

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let country of countries">
     <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img [src]="country.flag" />
     </ion-avatar>
     <h5>{{country.name}}</h5>
     <p>{{country.exchange_count}} Exchanges</p>
     <button ion-button primary outline item-end (click)="about(country)">View</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

home.ts

```
about(country){
  console.log(typeof(country))
  this.navCtrl.push(AboutPage, {country:country})
}
```

about.ts, the country's name is printed on the console

```
ionViewDidLoad () {
  this.country = this.navParams.get('country');
  console.log(this.country.name);
}
```

about.hmtl, here is where doing something like `country.name` raised an error `can't access property name of undefined` but when I do as below, the dumped data shows on the page.

```
<ion-content>
    {{country | json}}
    <!-- {{country.name}} -->
</ion-content>
```

on the about.html page, here is the result when piped into json, I trimmed the data for brevity

```
 {"id":"1","name":"Ghana","iso_code":"GHS","currency":"GHS",
"exchange_count":1}
```

I have tried several things, what am I missing?

Comment: what does  {{country | json}} shows?

Comment: it dumps the actual country object that was passed. Let me update the question with it

Comment: Try `{{ country?.name }}` - that'll make `country` optional, and not fail if it's not there. If it comes in at a later time, it'll read the property. The `json` pipe is fail safe to `undefined` inputs, which is why it seems to work better.

Comment: View is being generated before `ionViewDidLoad` method, therefore variable is still not initialized. Initialize it with an empty values in the constructor of your `AboutPage`. Something like `constructor() { public const country = {name:''}}`

Comment: thanks, both your solutions worked!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use safe navigation operator or ngif to verify the object is present , or you can initialize the country object as well.

```
<ion-content>
     {{country?.name}} 
</ion-content>
```

or

```
constructor() { public const country = {name:'',... etc}};
```

Comment: thank you! same solutions provided in the comments, can confirm it works.

Comment: oh yeah! i did not look at the comments though!

Comment: Been searching like an hour for the dumb '?'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had an object(*home*) that  has two properties *id* and *name*
When I tried to access them in the HTML, the console logged me following error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

So I had to add **ngIf* element to verify the object is present.

```
 <table class="table" *ngIf="homeToDelete">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="left">{{labels.id}}</th>
          <th>{{labels.name}}</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td class="left">{{homeToDelete.id}}</td>
          <td>{{homeToDelete.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```